# R - join data frames in an RDB-style, and converting multiple entries from one frame to a single entry in the other (string)

Tags: r, join, dataframe, sqldf

Sorry in advance for the long post.

Although I manage to overcome this using a for-loop, I have a feeling sqldf would be more efficient, but I could not get it right so far.

My first data frame has a unique identifier (Name). It is something like a 1000x5, but in the spirt of this:

```
Name <- c('Ben','Gary','John','Michael')
Age  <- c(13,20,5,57)
dfA  <- as.data.frame(cbind(Name,Age))

dfA
>        Name Age
>   1     Ben  13
>   2    Gary  20
>   3    John   5
>   4 Michael  57
```

My second data frame does NOT have a unique key, is also 5000x5, but looks generally like this:

```
Name   <- c('Ben','Ben','Ben','Gary','Michael','Michael','Michael')
Color  <- c('Blue','Red','Green','Red','Yellow','Yellow','Black')
Other.Entries <- c('180','200','150','100','70','200','130')
dfB   <- as.data.frame(cbind(Name,Color))

dfB
>     Name  Color  Other_Entries(not.related)
>1     Ben   Blue   180
>2     Ben    Red   180
>3     Ben  Green   150
>4    Gary    Red   100
>5 Michael Yellow   70
>6 Michael Yellow   200
>7 Michael  Black   130
```

Notice that there are redundancies in the Colors for each Names, and not all Names appear.

My desired output is to:

1. Retrieve the Color for each Name in data frame B (remove redundant, possibly alphabetically)
2. Convert these few Colors to a string (by using function "toString" for example)
3. Add the string as a new entry in the first data frame

At first when I used the for loop I created a new data frame with an empty column like this

```
dfCombined <- dfA
dfCombined["Color"] <- NA
```

.. and iterated over all rows, querying from the second data frame.

But perhaps this may not be necessary using something clever.

The end result should be:

```
dfCombined
>     Name Age    Color
>1     Ben  13   Blue, Green, Red
>2    Gary  20   Red
>3    John   5
>4 Michael  57   Black, Yellow
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1a) sqldf with multiple statements** Try this:

```
library(sqldf)

dfB_s <- sqldf("select distinct * from dfB order by Name, Color")
dfB_g <- sqldf("select Name, group_concat(Color) Color 
                from  dfB_s
                group by Name")
sqldf("select * 
       from dfA 
       left join dfB_g using (Name)")
```

**1b) sqldf with one statement** or all in one:

```
sqldf("select * 
       from dfA
       left join
             (select Name, group_concat(Color) Color 
             from 
                 (select distinct * from dfB order by Name, Color)
             group by Name)
       using (Name)")
```

Either of these gives:

```
     Name Age          Color
1     Ben  13 Blue,Green,Red
2    Gary  20            Red
3    John   5           <NA>
4 Michael  57   Black,Yellow
```

**2) without packages** Without sqldf it would be done like this:

```
dfB_s <- unique(dfB)[order(dfB$Name, dfB$Color), ]
dfB_g <- aggregate(Color ~ Name, dfB_s, toString)
merge(dfA, dfB_g, all.x = TRUE, by = "Name")
```

**3) data.table** If speed is the issue you might want to try data.table:

```
library(data.table)

unique(data.table(dfB, key = "Name,Color"))[
           , toString(Color), by = Name][
           data.table(dfA)]
```

giving:

```
      Name               V1 Age
1:     Ben Blue, Green, Red  13
2:    Gary              Red  20
3:    John               NA   5
4: Michael    Black, Yellow  57
```

**4) dplyr** and here is a dplyr solution:

library(dplyr)

```
dfA %.% 
   left_join(dfB %.%
                 unique() %.%
                 arrange(Name, Color) %.% 
                 group_by(Name) %.% 
                 summarise(Color = toString(Color)))
```

**ADDED** other solutions.  Fixed some errors.

Answer (score 0):

To batch process it do this in real code.
Psudo code:
Pull name
run while loop for color array
load array variable:$array = array("foo", "bar", "hello", "world");
var_dump($array);
run insert into new table for each name.

Comment: That would work. However I am dealing with large data frames that I'm pulling out of a database, something like 5000x5 each, where the "Name" and "Color" are non-unique in the second data frame. Any suggestions how to turn the second data frame into an array efficiently (if I understood you correctly)?